# Functional alternative to Javascript MV*?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, functional-programming

I like how Backbone.js provides conventions for structuring javascript frontend code according to OOD. Is there a similar framework or library which similarly provides conventions for interacting with the DOM, user events, and ajax...but in a functional style?

Edit:

For example, to change the name of a backbone "Person" model object:

```
person.set("name", "bob");
```

Which statefully modifies the "person" object and is not functional style. A functional alternative would make the models immutable and return new copies:

```
person = person.set("name", "bob");
```

Comment: Uhm.... jQuery? Could you elaborate on "functional style"? JavaScript is rather functional in itself.

Comment: Other than jQuery, there is also Ember.js and Angular.js ... Backbone.js is more of a library where Ember.js would involve you building your whole application around it.

Comment: that is a very interesting question. I don't know of any functional-style implementation of any libraries that act like Backbone, Ember, or any other MV* systems. I think this is largely due to the MV* style being centered around objects and object-oriented development patterns. Definitely going to watch this question and see if anyone knows of anything.

Comment: May i know the reason why you are looking for it? Javascript, being single threaded, I don't think it would protect you from anything. If you want to copy by value, just clone it. I think framework designers have the same mindset, therefore I doubt that there exists such a thing.

Comment: Is seems that there are none. It seems that functional programming has yet to catch on in the javascript community.

Comment: I believe that functional programming has other benefits which make unit testing much simpler and leads to cleaner code. For example, I would prefer to avoid sprinkling DOM manipulation throughout a large codebase.

Comment: I know this is old but try Fantasy Land. https://github.com/fantasyland/ You are specifically looking for fantasy-lenses. It doesn't do the actual model for you and it will need to be a plain object as it doesn't recreate the object. The old library that fantasy-land was inspired by is bilby.js. But you can get all that with fantasy-land. If you don't like doing L.mylens.run(myobject).set/get you can use point-free-fantasy-land.